# Factorial of a number in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, factorial

I am trying to find Factorial of a number but a unexpected output is coming. for 5 it should be 120 but 00 is coming. please Help in the following code Sometimes it goes into infinite loop.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
buffer db 10 dup('$')
n dw 5  
.code
main proc 

    mov ax , @data
    mov ds ,ax
    mov ax , n
    mov bx , offset buffer
    mov cx , 1 

 l1 : 

inc cx  
mul cx
cmp cx , n
jne l1

l2 : 
mov dx, 0 
mov cx ,10  
div cx 
add dl,48 
mov [bx], dl 
inc bx
cmp ax, 0 
jne l1      

mov dx , offset buffer ; moving address to dx
mov ah,9 ; printing string
int 21h

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h


main endp
end main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jump at the end of your `l2` loop is incorrect. You're jumping to `l1` when you should be jumping to `l2`.

Also, in your `l1` loop you `inc` and `mul` before you decide whether to exit the loop. So in the case where `n` is 5 you'll get `5 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5` (which is 600).

Comment: In addition to what Michael said, the output will be in reverse!